# how to return a 2D array from a function to the main function,and save it in another array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm coding a game "Tic Tac Toe"
and I ask each player to enter their next move in two different functions,
then I save their moves in 2D array, and save this array in another 2d array in the main function.
but when I print the array it changes the char symbol when the second player enters his next move.
PS: it's a char array.
here is my code

```
char player1(char board[N][N], int n)
{
    int  k, l;
    print_player_turn(1);
    scanf("%d%d", &k, &l);
    board[k - 1][l - 1] = 'X';
    print_board(board, n);
    return board;
}
char player2(char board[N][N], int n)
{
    int  k, l;
    print_player_turn(2);
    scanf("%d%d", &k, &l);
    board[k - 1][l - 1] = 'O';
    print_board(board, n);
    return board;
}
int main()
{
    char board[N][N];
    int n;
    print_welcome();
    print_enter_board_size();
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            board[i][j] = '_';
    print_board(board, n);
    char* ptr = board;
    while (isFull(board,n)==0)
    {
        board[0][0] = player1(board, n);
        if (XloseGeneral(board, n) == 1)
        {
            print_winner(2);
            return 0;
        }
        board[0][0] = player2(board, n);
        if (OloseGeneral(board, n) == 1)
        {
            print_winner(1);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    print_tie();

}
```

Comment: Arrays are always passed to functions as pointers. So any changes you make in an array within the function will be reflected in main. Which basically means you don't need to return the array and the assignment `board[0][0] = ` is completely un-necessary. Apart from that, I don't see any obvious problems.

Comment: Your compiler should show warnings for functions `player1` and `player2` because you try to return a wrong type. (The functions are expected to return a `char`, not a `char[][]`.) In C, an array is passed by reference, so you don't need to return the modified `board`. What do you want to achieve with `board[0][0] = player1(board, n);`? Currently it would convert the address of the first character in the array to a `char` and store this in the array at position `[0][0]`. Please [edit] your question to add more information. Change the return type to `void` and remove the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you expand the scope of the 2D array 'board' such that it is accessible to all methods including player 1 and player 2, instead of passing it as a parameter.

This way you can make sure that the modification is being done on the same variable, and that no reinitialisation happens, which results in loss of the previous entry.

Comment: This should be a comment. It doesn't answer the question. In addition to that, using global variables isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are passed to functions by reference. Which means, a pointer to the array is passed to the function. Hence, any modifications done to the array **inside** the function will reflect the caller (the main method in your case). So, make your function `void` as it doesn't need to return anything, and remove the `return` statement from it.

Comment: Close. You cannot pass an array to a function. When you try, it **decays into a pointer to its first element**. Since this decay happens both at the function declaration (`char player1(char board[N][N], int n)` is actually understood as `char player1(char (*board)[N], int n)` by the compiler) and at the function call (`player1(board, n)` is understood as `player1(&board[0], n)`), the *effect* is as if you had passed the array by reference. But all you did was to pass a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you don't need to return the board, you can just pass the pointer to the board. Here's a short example based on your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void player1(char **board);
void player2(char **board);
void print_board(char **board, int n);

void player1(char **board){
    int  k, l;
    fprintf(stderr, "Player 1, enter grid position:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &k, &l);
    board[k - 1][l - 1] = 'X';
}

void player2(char **board){
    int  k, l;
    fprintf(stderr, "Player 2, enter grid position:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &k, &l);
    board[k - 1][l - 1] = 'O';
}


void print_board(char **board, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
           fprintf(stdout, "%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    char **board; 
    fprintf(stdout, "Type in the board size:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // allocate memory for the board
    board = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        board[i] = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            board[i][j] = '_';
        }
    }

    print_board(board, n);

    player1(board);
    player2(board);

    print_board(board, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a pointer array, or double pointer indirection. The OPs approach with `char board[n][n]` is fine. And if you want to move the array to the heap, simply use `char (*board)[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(*board));`. The function prototype stays the same with that, as `char (*)[n]` is the type to which the array function arguments decay to anyways.